# How to solve and simplilfy equations and save multiple variables?

Tags: python, sympy

I have to calculate a system and get simplified outcomes. Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_unicode=True, wrap_line=True, no_global=True, use_latex=True)
c, k, n, z, beta, alpha, delta, chi, psi, A = symbols(r'c k n z \beta \alpha \delta \chi \psi A')
sol=solve([beta*(alpha*z*((k/n)**(alpha-1))+1-delta)-1,
       z*(k**alpha)*(n**(1-alpha))-delta*k-c,
       (1-alpha)*z*((k/n)**alpha)/c-chi*(n**psi),
      A-(1/beta-1+delta)     
      ], 
      (c,k,n))
```

But the outcome is very ugly and I don't know how to save c, k, and n respectively.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: The fourth equation, the A one, I just want to make the outcome more compact and define A.

Comment: What do you mean by "store"? Also, why should the outcome not be "ugly"? Are you able to solve the problem by hand? Did you try using this technique with a problem you can solve by hand?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It should be 'save'. I calculated them by hand but I need another way of verifying the results. People can not always calculate by hand for more complex ones. That is the meaning of technique.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "save". Exactly what do you see after running this code? What do you expect to see instead? Did you try reading the documentation for `solve`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Save the equations of c, k, and n so that I can use them in other calculations. I try to use the index to call the equation but failed.

Comment: I noticed that the third equation (1-alpha)*z*((k/n)**alpha)/c-chi*(n**psi) adds a gazillion lines to your output, could there be something wrong with that line?

Comment: "I try to use the index to call the equation but failed.", I'm not entirely sure what you expect, but there is only one element in the list that results from the call.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has become an obsession with me, but I'm not sure that it's not just a joke. The code runs in 58 seconds for me and it produces three solutions that are really only easily separated visually when I print using pprint. The first solution is ridiculously long. The other two seem somewhat credible, as an answer to who knows what though. I implemented JH's set(sol) method in this revised answer.(Answer? That's a stretch!)

```
import os
import sys
from sympy import *
import pprint
import time
start = time.time()
    
init_printing(use_unicode=True, wrap_line=True, no_global=True, use_latex=True)
c, k, n, z, beta, alpha, delta, chi, psi, A = symbols(r'c k n z \beta \alpha \delta \chi \psi A')
sol=solve([beta*(alpha*z*((k/n)**(alpha-1))+1-delta)-1,
           z*(k**alpha)*(n**(1-alpha))-delta*k-c,
           (1-alpha)*z*((k/n)**alpha)/c-chi*(n**psi),
          A-(1/beta-1+delta)     
          ], 
          (c, k, n))
print("the list of solutions is:")
pprint.pprint(set(sol)); print()
    
end = time.time()  
print('Code run time: ', end-start)
```

Comment: The expression `set(sol)` does the same as `unique(sol)`. But it does it in O(n) linear rather than O(n^2) quadratic time. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets